# Sharepoint: Access SQL sharepoint files

Tags: php, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, wss

I have the Sharepoint Intranet server on the same nework as the Internet PHP Web server. I would like to know if via PHP SQL code I can access a collection list of PDF files from the intranet so it can be viewed on the Internet site.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint exposes a [Lists web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists(office.12).aspx) to access List Items from a SharePoint List/Document Library.  You should be able to use this to grab document URLs and get that as a byte array or something, which you could serve up in your PHP application.  I'm not familiar with PHP, so I don't know what kind of web service support is offered, but you could always do it client-side with AJAX.